# How to make separators between buttons in ButtonBar?

Tags: android, button, buttonbar

I want to make a customized separators between buttons in my **button bar**, I put that button bar in a `HorizontalScrollView`, I had used two different ways to do that and both didn't work, The first one is placing a `View` between each two buttons like that:

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
        android:background="@drawable/released" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Main"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/main"/>

        <View android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="2px"
            android:background="@drawable/separators"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/HomeView"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Main"
            android:text="@string/homeview" />
        /! declaring the rest butttons and views!/
</RelativeLayout>
```

but when making that i got only one separator placed in the beginning in the button bar before all of the buttons.

---

The second one is to make a `divider` file and using the divider option in my **main.xml** like that:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:divider="@drawable/divider"
        android:dividerPadding="12dip"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
        android:background="@drawable/released" >

        /! declaring buttons !/
 </LinearLayout>
```

and **divider.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <size android:width="2dip" />
    <solid android:color="@drawable/separators" />

</shape>
```

where `separators` is a gradient color,

but this way gives me that error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.getDefaultProperties(RenderSessionImpl.java:1476)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.BridgeRenderSession.getDefaultProperties(BridgeRenderSession.java:68)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.ViewHierarchy.getDefaultProperties(ViewHierarchy.java:710)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.properties.XmlProperty.getStringValue(XmlProperty.java:209)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.properties.XmlProperty.getValue(XmlProperty.java:221)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.properties.BooleanXmlPropertyEditor.paint(BooleanXmlPropertyEditor.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.table.PropertyTable.drawProperty(PropertyTable.java:1309)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.table.PropertyTable.drawContent(PropertyTable.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.table.PropertyTable.handlePaint(PropertyTable.java:1094)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.table.PropertyTable.access$200(PropertyTable.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.model.property.table.PropertyTable$3.handleEvent(PropertyTable.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1081)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.WM_PRINTCLIENT(Composite.java:1667)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4673)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4977)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2443)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button.callWindowProc(Button.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4706)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4990)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2549)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your seperator placement between the buttons, as you're using `RelativeLayout` you'll need to mention exactly where do you want the seperator to be placed. Replacing the seperator `View` in your first layout with the below will give you the desired result:-

```
<View android:id="@+id/separator"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Main"
android:layout_width="2px"
android:background="@drawable/separators"/>
```

and also make the following change in the `HomeView` button

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/HomeView"
 android:layout_width="120dp"
 android:layout_height="50dp"
 android:background="@android:color/transparent"
 android:textColor="@android:color/white"
 android:textStyle="bold"
 android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Separator"
 android:text="@string/homeview" />
```